# Why must my coffeescript method belong to the class?

Tags: coffeescript

I come from a C#/Java background which use a class based OO system and I don't get the JavaScript/CoffeeScript prototype OO system yet.  I've written a CoffeeScript class below which allows me to display names for contacts according to a system-side preference.  I can only get the class to work by making the `joinNonEmpty(stringList, joinText)` method belong to the prototype and calling it the way I would call a static method in Java/C# land.

1. Is there a way I can make this method call using `this.joinNonEmpty(...)`?
2. Can you shed some light on why I can reference the `firstLastRender, lastFirstRender and firstOrNickThenLast` methods in the constructor with this. but it doesn't work from those methods when calling the `joinNonEmpty` helper?
3. Does this have something to do with how I'm locating the appropriate method via the preference map?

```
prefs = displayNameFormat: "FirstOrNickThenLast"

class DisplayNameRenderer

    constructor: ->
        @prefToRenderMap =
            FirstLast: this.firstLastRender
            LastFirst: this.lastFirstRender
            FirstOrNickThenLast: this.firstOrNickThenLast

    # Why does this method have to be static (a class method)?
    @joinNonEmpty: (stringList, joinText) ->
        nonEmptyStrings = []
        for s in stringList
            nonEmptyStrings.push(s) if s isnt null and s isnt ""
        nonEmptyStrings.join(joinText)

    firstLastRender: (contact) ->
        # TypeError: Object expected.
        joinNonEmpty([contact.firstName, contact.lastName], ' ')

    lastFirstRender: (contact) ->
        # TypeError: Object doesn't support this method or property
        this.joinNonEmpty([contact.lastName, contact.firstName], ', ')

    firstOrNickThenLast: (contact) ->
        # Works correctly.
        DisplayNameRenderer.joinNonEmpty([(if contact.nickname isnt null and contact.nickname isnt "" then contact.nickname else contact.firstName), contact.lastName], ' ')

    render: (contact) ->
        @prefToRenderMap[prefs.displayNameFormat](contact)

contact = firstName: "Jonathan", nickname: "Jonny", lastName: "Appleseed"

dnr = new DisplayNameRenderer()

 # => "Jonny Appleseed"
console.log dnr.render(contact)
```

Thanks for taking the time to answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`this` (AKA `@`) is determined when the function is called (with exceptions as below). So when you do this:

```
@prefToRenderMap =
    FirstLast: this.firstLastRender
    LastFirst: this.lastFirstRender
    FirstOrNickThenLast: this.firstOrNickThenLast
```

You're storing unbound references to the three functions in the `@prefToRenderMap` instance variable and `@prefToRenderMap` is itself an object. Then you try to call the methods in your `DisplayNameRenderer` instance like this:

```
@prefToRenderMap[prefs.displayNameFormat](contact)
```

and everything falls apart because the methods are called in the wrong context and `@` isn't what they're expecting it to be. If `prefs` is `'FirstOrNickThenLast'` then you're effectively doing this:

```
@prefToRenderMap.FirstOrNickThenLast(contact)
```

and `@` (AKA `this`) will be `@prefToRenderMap` inside the `firstOrNickThenLast` method. But, of course, `@prefToRenderMap` doesn't have any of the methods that you're trying to call so you get various errors.

One solution is to use the [fat arrow (`=>`)](http://coffeescript.org/#fat_arrow) to define the methods:

> The fat arrow `=>` can be used to both define a function, and to bind it to the current value of `this`, right on the spot.

So you could have things like this:

```
joinNonEmpty: (stringList, joinText) ->
    #...

firstLastRender: (contact) =>
    @joinNonEmpty([contact.firstName, contact.lastName], ' ')
```

and everything will work out. Here's a stripped down demo that will also show you your `this` problem:

> http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/RAPJw/1/

You could also avoid this problem by referring to the methods by their names. Given a method name in a string, `m = 'some_method'`, you can call that method like this `o[m]()` in both JavaScript and CoffeeScript and the result will be the same as if you said `o.some_method()`. A better structure would look more like this:

```
class DisplayNameRenderer
    constructor: ->
        @prefToRenderMap =
            FirstOrNickThenLast: 'firstOrNickThenLast'

    joinNonEmpty: (stringList, joinText) ->
        #...

    firstOrNickThenLast: (contact) ->
        @joinNonEmpty([(if contact.nickname isnt null and contact.nickname isnt "" then contact.nickname else contact.firstName), contact.lastName], ' ')

    render: (contact) ->
        @[@prefToRenderMap['FirstOrNickThenLast']](contact)
```

Note the change to the structure of `@prefToRenderMap` and how it is used in `render`. And a demo of this approach: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/DFYwu/

---

As an aside, instead of saying `ClassName.class_method()` inside an instance method, you can use the [`constructor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor) property instead: `@constructor.class_method()`. Also, you usually say `@method()` or `@property` rather than `this.method()` and `this.property` in CoffeeScript.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, thank you.  I understand what is happening with the scope now.